# It is possible to disassemble a Firefox XPCOM?

Tags: firefox, xpcom, disassembly

it is possible to restore (pseudo) code from a Firefox XPCOM DLL?
I know there is a Firefox plugin called [XPCOMViewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/af/firefox/addon/7979/) what shows me classes and interfaces and this works fine but I need more to know about what this XPCOM do.

The plugin has a function "Generate Code", anyway nothing happens when I try to do this.

Have you any advice for me how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a regular DLL and can be disassembled as any other executable. If you expect to get something more understandable than assembly, then no - XPCOM DLLs are regular DLLs built according to special conventions.